# Mac os sierra slow work php-imap cli

Tags: php, macos, imap

When install valet like it described in laravel docs my first step installing php71  I use brew install homebrew/php/php71 --with-imap. I added imap option cause my project use it. Then i install other mysql and vallet. All works fine but big problem slow work php-cli. It takes 5sec before script runs. If I will remove imap extension it works fast. But I need imap extension.  I try to add
127.0.0.1   hostname.local 
to /etc/hosts but it does not work. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

I already had the ::1 and I needed to change the address to point to my local hostname

`::1         localhost YourMac.local
127.0.0.1   localhost YourMac.local`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding Your hostname.local as `::1` additionally to `127.0.0.1`, this worked for me.

And yes, this is a known php_imap issue.